# What is the official term for vertical line that connects code

Tags: intellij-idea, ide, terminology

When I am working in an IDE, I always see this line that visually shows the start and end of a method, for loop, if-else statement, etc:

[image: This i what i am talking about]

I was wondering does anybody know what this is officially called? I would like to know this so that I can research how to implement one in my own program.

Comment: This is just a visual help of your IDE - I don't think there's an official term for for.

Comment: @DirkR This is true. However, I have seen this on forum sites and on Reddit as well sort of like to connect answers together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intellij refers to these as **Indent Guides** and from googling that seems to be an accepted term for what you are describing.

Note:

In IntelliJ you can toggle them on and off **Settings | Editor | General | Appearance | Show indent guides**